# Removing white spaces in a string that contains a number that needs to be casted as a double (Pyspark)

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have the following string that has the format on decimals in the following ways (I need to remove the spaces and be able to recognize the format in parenthesis as a negative):

```
- '   123.23 '
- '   -123.34'
-  ' (123.23)  '
-  ' -  123.34. '
```

I have tried the following ways:

```
1.- df = df.withColumn("column_name", trim(df.column_name))
2.- df = df.withColumn("column_name" , regexp_replace("column_name","\s+", ""))
3.- df = df.select(regexp_replace(col("column_name"),"\\s+",""))
4.- df = df.withColumn('column_name', regexp_extract(col("column_name"), r'^(.*?):([\(\)(\,)0-9.]+)', 5))
```

none of those options have work so far, I'm thinking of regex so it runs faster, but it can be other ways

Answer (score 0):

following is working.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
df = sc.parallelize([
 ("   123.23 ",),
 ("   -123.34",),
 (" (123.23)  ",),
 (" -  123.34. ",)]
 ).toDF(["value"])
# df.show()
df2 = df.withColumn('extracted_value', regexp_extract(col("value"), r'(\d+.\d+)', 1))
df2.show()
```

**Output**:

```
+------------+---------------+
|       value|extracted_value|
+------------+---------------+
|     123.23 |         123.23|
|     -123.34|         123.34|
|  (123.23)  |         123.23|
| -  123.34. |         123.34|
+------------+---------------+
```

And if you want `-` sign as well. use following code

```py
df2 = df.withColumn('extracted_value', regexp_extract(regexp_replace(col("value"), "\\s+", ""), r'(-?\d+.\d+)', 1))
```

**Output**

```
+------------+---------------+
|       value|extracted_value|
+------------+---------------+
|     123.23 |         123.23|
|     -123.34|        -123.34|
|  (123.23)  |         123.23|
| -  123.34. |        -123.34|
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gaurang. for some reason the (-) sign doesn't show up which is kind of important, and I'm using the exact same expression. but I do get the values

Comment: @WendyVelasquez did you try second option. may be your data is different that what I have shoed in `value` field

Comment: I did, and the numbers showed up but not as negatives that's the only thing

Comment: how's your `value` or source column looks like ?

Comment: is a bit inconsistent, as you could see on my initial statement, those are the I have identified when negatives are being read.

Comment: so is it coming with `-  ' -  123.34. '` with quotes and first `-` ?

Comment: those values are currently as strings, so those quotes should not be a problem if that is a a string is just a distinctive way of writing it ' Im a string'  type of writing in the initial statement